# In BigQuery, create ARRAY of STRUCTs from longer data when grouping-by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have a table of player info, with unique rows for each name-year-team:

```
with
  player_info as (
    select 'joe' as name, 1950 as year, 'bills' as team union all
    select 'joe' as name, 1950 as year, 'jazz' as team union all
    select 'joe' as name, 1951 as year, 'jazz' as team union all
    select 'joe' as name, 1952 as year, 'rafs' as team union all
    select 'nick' as name, 1950 as year, 'bills' as team union all
    select 'nick' as name, 1951 as year, 'bills' as team union all
    select 'chris' as name, 1950 as year, 'jazz' as team union all
    select 'chris' as name, 1951 as year, 'jazz' as team union all
    select 'sal' as name, 1950 as year, 'dopers' as team
  )
  
select * from player_info
```

[image]

We need a unique row for each **player**, with a struct containing the year-team informations:

```
SELECT 'joe' AS name, [
  struct(1950 as year, 'bills' as team),  
  struct(1950 as year, 'jazz' as team),
  struct(1951 as year, 'jazz' as team),  
  struct(1952 as year, 'rafs' as team)
] as team_years

union all

SELECT 'nick' as name, [
    struct(1950 as year, 'bills' as team),  
    struct(1951 as year, 'bills' as team)
] as team_years

union all 

SELECT 'chris' as name, [
    struct(1950 as year, 'jazz' as team),  
    struct(1951 as year, 'jazz' as team)
] as team_years

union all

select 'sal' as name, [
    struct(1950 as year, 'dopers' as team)
] as team_years
```

[image]

How can we do this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
select name, array_agg(struct(year, team) order by year) as team_years
from player_info
group by name
```